# Why do I get error message of "logname: no login name" in linux?

Tags: linux, users, login

Whenever I connect to SSH session to a remote server, with either mobaXterm or just windows command line, there shows a message that says `/usr/bin/logname: no login name`

I can edit files and see directories normally however.

I tested with command `logname` and it returns `logname: no login name`, same with `/usr/bin/logname`

However when I type `whoami` or `/usr/bin/whoami`, it returns my id properly. and when I type `id` it also returns a line of information containing my id. The command `who am i` however return nothing.

`logname 2>/dev/null || echo ${SUDO_USER:-${USER}}` this also works from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424237/who-w-logname-broken-in-multiple-terminals)

What exactly is the problem here? I am unable to install Pycharm because of this error.

System is redhat linux. I do not have sudo rights.

My `.profile` looks like `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH`

and my `.bashrc` looks like

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:....(not relevant) 
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and my `.bash_profile` looks like
`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Your login methods are not starting a login shell, or more precisely, are not indicating to the login process that you need an entry in `/run/utmp`. (Maybe `/var/log/utmp`, `/var/run/utmp`, or even `/etc/utmp`.) So:

```
ssh -q remoteHost logname
logname: no login name
```

but

```
ssh -qt remoteHost logname
roaima
```

However, unlike you, if I connect normally I do get a login shell that creates an entry in `/run/utmp`:

```
ssh remoteHost

logname
roaima

who am i
roaima   pts/0        2022-06-20 23:12 (192.168.1.137)
```

There should be an option in `mobaXterm` to start a login shell, which usually forces the missing entry in `/run/utmp`. If you're using gnome-terminal there is a report of [something similar](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1710949). Without knowing how you are connecting from the "*windows command line*" I can't offer further advice there.

Comment: I just tried ssh -t myid@serveraddress logname, it gives the same error .. could not find login shell option in mobaXterm.. I checked there is indeed no /etc/utemp/ ... this is a company server, is it something about restriction set by IT?

Comment: @user530619 I've updated the location of `utmp` to match modern Linux systems running `systemd`. Please notice it's `utmp` not `utemp/`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I found this file `/var/un/utmp` exists.  but `/usr/bin/logname: no login name` still happens every time i connect ? Another piece of info: `whoami` return id properly, but `who am i` does not return anything...